# Adding an onclick to a submenu?

Tags: android, menu, onclick, submenu

I have an onclick function for my menu but I can't figure out what the ID is for my submenu so that I can tell the submenu what to do when the user click on it. I created my submenu programmatically using the code below. So if someone could please explain to me how I know what the id is for each item of the submenu I'd greatly appreciate it.

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);

    SubMenu submenu = menu.addSubMenu(0, Menu.FIRST, Menu.NONE, "Preferences");
    submenu.add(0, Menu.FIRST, Menu.NONE, "Get Last 5 Packets");
    submenu.add(0, Menu.FIRST, Menu.NONE, "Get Last 10 Packets");
    submenu.add(0, Menu.FIRST, Menu.NONE, "Get Last 20 Packets");
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, submenu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.viewKML:
            viewKML();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you are adding

```
submenu.add(0, Menu.FIRST, Menu.NONE, "Get Last 5 Packets");
```

The parameter arrangement for add() method is [Android Menu Add Method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#add%28int,%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

```
public abstract MenuItem add (int groupId, int itemId, int order, CharSequence title)
```

> itemId    Unique item ID. Use NONE if you do not need a unique ID.

Is the id of your menu item. It should be unique. Like you say 15,20,21. This id will act like `android:id="@+id/15"`. Is will be used when you are going to check which item is clicked

e.g

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_menu, menu);

        SubMenu submenu = menu.addSubMenu(0, Menu.FIRST, Menu.NONE, "Preferences");
        submenu.add(0, 10, Menu.NONE, "Get Last 5 Packets");
        submenu.add(0, 15, Menu.NONE, "Get Last 10 Packets");
        submenu.add(0, 20, Menu.NONE, "Get Last 20 Packets");
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_menu, submenu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 10:
            Toast.makeText(LoginPageActivity.this, "Now "+item.getItemId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case 15:
            Toast.makeText(LoginPageActivity.this, "Now = "+item.getItemId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case 20:
            Toast.makeText(LoginPageActivity.this, "Now == "+item.getItemId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you @Arslan. Found this after a long search.

Comment: Can u help me in changing the colour of the submenu items? I searched the code of ABS but couldnt get it. @RandomlyKnighted?