# Detect KeyPress on ActionBarSherlock SubMenu

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, submenu

How do I detect keypress and which key user pressed on SubMenu? [the one on the actionbar where user press and a long list would drop down]

```
 SubMenu subMenu1 = menu.addSubMenu("Option");
        subMenu1.add("Comments");
        subMenu1.add("More screens");
        subMenu1.add("Copy Website URL");
        subMenu1.add("Go to Website");

        MenuItem subMenu1Item = subMenu1.getItem();
        subMenu1Item.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_share);
        subMenu1Item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        finish();
        break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you mean "which item a user selects" in the menu, and not "which key a user pressed". You can provide the action in the `onOptionsItemSelected()` method that you already have. But before, you have to...

- *Either* change the way that you programmatically add items to your subMenu a little, following this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9080046/1140682
- *Or* [define your menu and submenu in an XML file](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#xml) and use the `MenuInflater` to add the items to your `Activity`.

Finally, just use the `itemId` parameter from the `add()` method (first solution) *or* the `android:id` from the XML (second solution) to decide on an action in the `switch` statement of `onOptionsItemSelected()`.

Comment: Can u help me in changing the colour of the submenu items @saschoar? I searched the code of ABS and in abs_styles.xml, in  <style name="Widget.Sherlock.ListPopupWindow" parent="Widget">, i changed popupbackground, but nothing happens?